# App script to loop though Google Sheets and cel range then gets a matching sheet to file id then copy data to id file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Narration:**
I am a newbie to app script, I have a spreadsheet which has several sheets named after different client. Also, I have in the sheet named “Customer” a range of customer name and file ID of the original customer files on my drive

**Objective:**
I want to loop through the sheets (A,B,C,D ETC) and copy the values in each sheet and then loop through the range in the sheet named “customer”  get the corresponding file ID for the particular customer. 
Then to open the corresponding customer file, paste the data into the file and go on looping to the next sheet and get subsequent spreadsheet file of the next customer and so on.
All help is well appreciated.
My Example Spreadsheet is here [my sample spreadsheet][1]

**My Code**: am not sure how to proceed. (I really want to learn)

```
 function updatefile() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sh = ss.getSheetByName('CUSTOMER')
 var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues(); // get the range of non emmpty cells
 var allsheets = ss.getSheets(); // get an array of all sheets and their name
  // Array holding the names of the sheets to exclude from the execution
    var exclude = ["ALL_CUSTOMER_ORDERS","CUSTOMER","TEMPLATE"];
   for(var s in allsheets){
    var sheet = allsheets[s];
  // Stop iteration execution if the condition is meet.
     if(exclude.indexOf(sheet.getName())==-1) continue;
```

Comment: Welcome. The link to your Example Spreadsheet failed. Please edit your question to update the link. I must say that for a newbie, that is a very sophisticated script. I'm looking forward to seeing the example worksheet.

Comment: I am flattered. well i was able to find my way around the challenge. This could be found in my other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891012/copy-dynamic-range-from-one-spreadsheet-to-another-spreadsheet-called-with-getfi

Comment: Congrats on answering your own question. Its important for the long term