# copy dynamic range from one spreadsheet to another spreadsheet called with getfileid

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to do the following:

- Loop through column "A" in "Customer" and get corresponding sheet name.
- Get the sheet and copy all used range in sheet, e.g (A;B;C;etc) to the specific files referenced in column B.

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
function updatefile() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('CUSTOMER')
  var data = sh.getRange("A2:B12").getValues(); // get the range of non empty cells
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var source = ss.getSheetByName(data[i][0]);
    var range = source.getRange('C3:M1003'); //assign the range you want to copy
    var data = range.getValues();

    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(data[i][1]); // open the corresponding file by using the file id in the second column 
    var destbodya = destination.getSheetByName('UPDATE ON ORDERS');
    destbodya.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1,49,7).setValues(data); //you will need to define the size of the copied data see getRange()
  }
}
```

[Link to my Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u5z77IamlMyb8c1YuIHcJFyEk9cIpS_RvzmP6P6AYas/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work after a lot of searching and trials. for those who comes by such challenges. Cheers

```
function updatefile() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('CUSTOMER')
  var data = sh.getRange("A2:B73").getValues(); // get the range of non emmpty cells
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] != '') {
      var source = ss.getSheetByName(data[i][0]);
      var range = source.getRange('C3:M1003'); //assign the range you want to copy
      var valuedata = range.getValues();

      //var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxrrrrrsomeID"); // enter file ID directly or the nest line
      var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(data[i][1]); // Iterate through the range and open the corresponding file by using the file id in the secound column 
      var dest_1body = destination.getSheetByName('blah blah sheetname'); // first sheet destination to copy data to
      dest_1body.getRange("A2:K1002").setValues(valuedata); //you will need to define the size of the copied data see getRange()

      var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(data[i][1]); // open the coresponding file by using the file id in the secound column
      var dest_2body = destination.getSheetByName('blah blah sheetname'); // second sheet to copy same data to

      dest_2body.getRange("A28:K1028").setValues(valuedata); //you will need to define the size of the copied data see getRange()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: **Line4**: the range A2:B73 creates a data.length of 72 but there are only 11 values in the range. You might be better off getting the last row ` var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();` and use that to get the range
**Line5**: when you got the range in line 4, you already took into account the header in row 1. So `var i = 1` skips Customer A completely. It should be: `var i = 0`
**Line8**: is this an actual range or a guesstimate? 
**Line12**: `var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(data[i][1]);` fails should be `data[1][i]`.
**Line16/17**: Isn't this a duplication of Line12/13?